# Complex dynamic programming, how to define overlapping subproblems

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The producer wants to hire new workers. Every new worker brings additional value for the company. Every next worker in the same division brings equal or less value than one before him. E.g.

```
 Division #1: Division #2: ...
 0: 0         0
 1: 30        35
 2: 55        65
 3: 78        90
 4: 97        110
 5: 115       .
 6: 131       .
 7: 144       .
 8: 154
 9: 160
10: 163
```

Producer wants to add additional $250 value to its company with as few new workers as possible. How should he distribute new workers between departments.

EDIT: As comments demanded: if you add 0 workers to `Division #1` you have $0 increase of company value.

---

I need to know how to define subprolems.

I can't cope with the fact that after adding every worker for next workers table is changed. Namely changed the column of division where worker was put in. So, i can't just say that i have the same problem with just less new value to acquire.

Comment: I think i'm not understanding.  How do you define how much a new worker will add (besides knowing the maximum).  Also, i dont understand how adding a worker changes anything. (Besides the value of the company)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat , thank you, it is the best way to tackle such problem, but i want to learn DP. That's why i asking. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Yola what is division 1 ,2 you don't define it in the statement and what are the values written in the figure can you please elaborate what exactly you want to achieve with an example ?

Comment: @Yola why are the values increasing downward, you said new workers have equal or less values , am I missing something ? Also could you exactly define the input parameters of the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let v(i, j) be the value in dollars that j new workers bring to the i-th division. This is essentially the transposed table from your question.

With n departments, you are looking for a sequence of natural numbers w<sub>1</sub>, ..., w<sub>n</sub> such that SUM(i = 1..n, w<sub>i</sub>) is minimal and SUM(i = 1..n, v(i, w<sub>i</sub>)) ≥ 250.

The main observation is that if you have assigned w<sub>i</sub> to w<sub>k</sub> already for some k, you don't need to know the exact assignment to solve the remaining subproblem of assigning w<sub>k+1</sub> to w<sub>n</sub>. You just need to know how many workers you already assigned and how much value you already added. You can basically reduce the space of possible assignments for w<sub>i</sub> to w<sub>k</sub> (which is exponentially large) to two integral values that represent all the information you care about. In fact, we don't even care about all combinations of (a = number of workers, b = value), only those that are not superseded by some other pair (c, d) with c <= d and d >= b).

You can define f(i, x) as the minimum total number of workers for w<sub>1</sub>, .., w<sub>i</sub> such that the added value is ≥ x.

Obviously we have f(0, 0) = 0 and f(0, x) = ∞ for x > 0. The infinity value represents that is impossible to achieve this situation.

We can also proof the recurrence

f(i + 1, x) = MIN(w = 0 to ∞, f(i, max(0, x - v(i + 1, w))))

which leads to a simple DP algorithm to compute f.

The function value you are interested in is f(n, 250).